# Create gradle dependency library with including transitive dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am creating a library named XYZ and the library has included some other libraries as `Gradle` dependencies.

I have uploaded the library XYZ to the `jcenter` and now it's able to include as a `Gradle` dependency. But when I include the library XYZ, I also need to manually include all the transitive libraries in the XYZ.

Is there any way that, it can automatically download the transitive dependencies when I include the library XYZ.

Comment: Check the pom file in jcenter. It should include all transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a pom file with your dependencies and pack it with your library

Comment: I have created the pom file, how to pack it with my library?